# Logback leaving .tmp files with multiple instances in Jboss with springBoot

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, jboss, logback

We are deploying the application in multiple instances of JBoss. We log back with version 1.1.11 and spring-boot 1.5.10. When log back is trying to append the log file and rolling back as a .zip file it's leaving .tmp files. Below is the scenario

When the application is running in three instances, it's appending only one instance logs into the zip leaving other two instances as .tmp files, which actually should be appended under the same zip file. This is a blocker in our production, with this behavior we are unable to trace out the issue.

```
<configuration>
<property resource="bootstrap.yml" />
<springProperty name="appName" source="spring.application.name"/>
<springProperty name="loglevel" source="logging.level.com.some.package"/>

<appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
<encoder>
<pattern>%d {ISO8601}%-5p [%c{3}] [%t] %m%n</pattern>
</encoder>
</appender>
<appender name ="APPLICATION" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
<file>/appllogs/spp/$
{appName}.log</file>
<rollingPolicy
class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
<fileNamePattern>/appllogs/backup/${appName}/%d{yyyy-MM-dd}  
%i.log.zip</fileNamePattern>
<maxHistory>7</maxHistory>
<timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
<maxFileSize>50MB</maxFileSize>
</timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
<totalSizeCap>1GB</totalSizeCap>
</rollingPolicy>

<encoder>
<pattern>%d %-5p %m%n</pattern>
</encoder>
</appender>

<logger name="com.some.package" level="$
{loglevel}" additivity="false">
<appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
<appender-ref ref="APPLICATION"/>
</logger>

<root level="${loglevel}

" >
<appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
<appender-ref ref="APPLICATION"/>
</root>
</configuration>
```